# Converting MongoDB query do PyMongo format

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

Folks,

I have a MongoDB query that I would like to execute in my Python code:

```
db.authentication.aggregate(
    {$group:{_id:{'cpf':"$person.cpf", 'data':"$created_at"}, 'chamadas':{$push:"$device_data.metaChamadas.duration"}}},
    {$project:{
        'cpf':"$_id.cpf",
        'tamanho':{$size:{$arrayElemAt:["$chamadas",0]}}
    }}
)
```

I´m using the Mongoengine since it supports raw PyMongo queries but I can´t figure out the conversion so far:

```
documents = list(Authentication.objects(__raw__={

PYMONGO QUERY HERE

}).limit(10))
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All [`mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.aggregate) have an aggregate method that can be called with aggregation commands as arguments.

Translating your MongoDb query, you should have a query like so:

```
pipeline = (
        {
        '$group': {
            '_id': {
                'cpf': '$person.cpf',
                'data': '$created_at'
            }, 
            'chamadas': {
                '$push': '$device_data.metaChamadas.duration'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        '$project': {
            'cpf': '$_id.cpf',
            'tamanho':  {
                '$size': {
                    '$arrayElemAt': ['$chamadas', 0]
                }
            }
        }
    }    
)

data = Authentication.objects.aggregate(*pipeline)
print(list(data))
```